# getting text dynamically from EditableText android

Tags: android

i am trying to get the text input/values from an EditText widget as its being typed. please anybody know how or which method i should use? can't seem to find one that will help. thanks for your consideration.

i tried this but not working:

```
  Entry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.typeEntryId);
          viewEntry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewEntryId);

       if(Entry != null){
            //viewEntry.setText(Entry.getEditableText().toString());
                  viewEntry.setText(Entry.getText().toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myField);
if ( field != null ) {
  Log.d ("myField",field.getText().toString());
}
```

you should be able to just do that. The [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) method returns an [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) type which implements [CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

Comment: yeah, i tried that buts its not working, if i am trying to display it in another text view. i even tried getEditableText(). i have edited my question to show the code i tried.